# Python/Pandas: How to do a join on matches across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, match

**Problem:**

I would like to join two tables together using a more complex joining criteria. One table has 3 different possible phone numbers, and the other table has 2 different possible phone numbers. I do not know which is the main phone number for each row. As such, I would like to join based on the criteria that a phone number from the `number`, `Phone1`, `Phone2` columns in the first Table can be found in either the `ANI` or `DNIS` columns in the second Table.

**Sample Data:**

One DataFrame Looks like this...

```
                           application_uuid      number      Phone1      Phone2
0      b7754a2e-84be-4aec-a04e-0eba93dca5d8  5196942368         NaN         NaN
1      6ca3f0c3-0c83-4ebd-afe3-23977f1c6608  6475219092         NaN         NaN
2      3b5a083e-7765-4f27-941d-d2b4cbd6f26a  6476256563         NaN         NaN
3      229fee54-437f-4812-abec-7034fcb9a655        None         NaN         NaN
4      866a2cd2-5628-4e6b-b649-d92e2f0585ce  7092164418  7096391545  7092164977
5      8259410d-8d3d-4381-a0b3-6d6ce67b0917  6476387217  6476387217  6475313526
6      c359b03b-5e5f-4d4e-a5b0-ee37ac90c292        None         NaN         NaN
7      d70414a9-8fd9-4d1d-a77d-17f06743fd00  7054987969         NaN         NaN
8      0452edf9-2d58-4ad5-b1e2-0621ac517104  6136219401         NaN         NaN
9      cb3ab85c-fd42-4aff-a9b8-1743565b31e6        None         NaN         NaN
10     563e3e4d-e59a-4afc-b804-91aa14de919d  7056582202  7056582202  7056584200
11     3dd1df61-a36f-490b-ac15-225a83a21551        None  7096899998  7096899998
12     6bc42df3-e869-4794-a595-e3238ccf5284  5873415009         NaN         NaN
13     8bf11117-038f-4d2d-b4c6-9b2c6423d626  6473435642         NaN         NaN
14     0a854fe5-af66-40b0-b202-3e9367dc5a75  6478594204         NaN         NaN
15     b5884de8-2e0c-4b38-a3fd-7911cf4840b1  7787075288  7787075288  7787075288
16     f74cf212-cff0-48cc-b210-539dcdcccf72  7802676838  7806678567        None
17     9bffe5bf-b5d8-4e74-b4c9-9f1b5b238af3        None         NaN         NaN
18     dce91c00-a1ea-4111-a6ee-5ff5fd0cfb5f  6476093140         NaN         NaN
19     29cd024e-2c51-4682-b274-809c3cfb2b2b        None         NaN         NaN
20     ec55317b-fc20-416a-b26d-e95300f89c79        None         NaN         NaN
21     b3d00cd8-9d8e-415e-99b1-d8944e7b31e1        None         NaN         NaN
22     b3328787-edb7-4e08-a76c-370a74135fba        None         NaN         NaN
23     c8baf235-e702-41db-b4f8-8c2bf38109bf        None         NaN         NaN
24     cd9179bc-0594-4d25-9d7f-ddf6671777e2  7802428155         NaN         NaN
25     370855c0-b3fa-4d87-8d54-b84d34e7f35f        None         NaN         NaN
26     82244e78-3802-4890-96f6-e5267172f0e9        None         NaN         NaN
27     c7b0054c-29ac-4c76-bc5d-8cdbc93f5157  7052093358  7055268791  7052093358
28     d90e6e87-f7ef-43e1-9c85-35572fae838c  4039696044         NaN         NaN
29     bdd2474f-f4be-402b-8672-d73da90d7066        None         NaN         NaN
```

The other DataFrame looks like this...

```
        CALL ID CALL TYPE         ANI          DNIS TALK TIME
0        615262   Inbound  6479246923  8.557236e+09  00:00:00
1        615263   Inbound  5196519186  8.557236e+09  00:00:00
2        615264   Inbound  7095679350  8.557236e+09  00:00:00
3        615265   Inbound  7095679350  8.557236e+09  00:00:00
4        615266   Inbound  7095679350  8.557236e+09  00:00:00
5        615267   Inbound  7095679350  8.557236e+09  00:00:00
6        615268   Inbound  7095679350  8.557236e+09  00:00:00
7        615269   Inbound  7095679350  8.557236e+09  00:00:00
8        615270   Inbound  7095679350  8.557236e+09  00:00:00
9        615271   Inbound  7095679350  8.557236e+09  00:00:00
10       615272   Inbound  4035634231  8.557236e+09  00:00:00
11       615273   Inbound  7095679350  8.557236e+09  00:00:00
12       615274   Inbound  7095679350  8.557236e+09  00:00:00
13       615275   Inbound  7095679350  8.557236e+09  00:00:00
14       615276   Inbound  7095679350  8.557236e+09  00:00:00
15       615277   Inbound  7095679350  8.557236e+09  00:00:00
16       615278   Inbound  7095679350  8.557236e+09  00:00:00
17       615279   Inbound  9057972416  8.557236e+09  00:00:00
18       615280   Inbound  9057972416  8.557236e+09  00:00:00
19       615281   Inbound  9057972416  8.557236e+09  00:00:00
20       615282    Manual  8557235626  8.005635e+09  00:00:11
21       615283   Inbound  9057972416  8.557236e+09  00:00:00
22       615284   Inbound  4169991603  8.557236e+09  00:00:00
23       615285    Manual  8557235626  4.162977e+09  00:01:05
24       615286    Manual  8557235626  8.002569e+09  00:00:55
25       615287   Inbound  4169967207  8.557236e+09  00:07:48
26       615288   Inbound  4169788047  8.557236e+09  00:01:29
27       615289   Inbound  9057972416  8.557236e+09  00:01:39
28       615290   Inbound  8002568964  8.557236e+09  00:04:21
29       615291    Manual  8557235626  7.059751e+09  00:00:19
```

**My Approach:**

My approach was to append the phone numbers within in each row as a single column in a list. Then I created a search function. This way is not practical, inelegant and much too slow.

```
def f(row):
    phone_numbers_59 = phone_data['Number'].tolist()
    callid = phone_data['CALL ID'].tolist()

    get_callid = []
    for i in range(0, len(phone_numbers_59)):
        if any([x in phone_numbers_59[i] for x in row['Numbers']]):
            get_callid.append(callid[i])

    if len(get_callid) > 0:
        return get_callid
    else:
        return "NA"

s = data.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: The first thing you need to do is clean your data: DNIS is a float dtype which is very wrong.  Phone numbers are best treated as strings, but if you care a lot about speed you may prefer to use int.  If you have NaN values, do `.fillna(-1).astype(int)` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `number`, `Phone1`, `Phone2` can be found in either `ANI` or `DNIS`

It's simpler if you take the conditions one at a time (and don't write big `for` loops in Python, which as you've seen is slow):

```
for col in ('ANI', 'DNIS'):
    right = df2.set_index(col, drop=False)
    df1 = df1.join(right, 'number', rsuffix='_num_'+col)
    df1 = df1.join(right, 'Phone1', rsuffix='_p1_'+col)
    df1 = df1.join(right, 'Phone2', rsuffix='_p2_'+col)
```

What this does is to add columns to `df1` six times: once for each combination.  `rsuffix` serves to disambiguate the column names.  You may end up with multiple matches (perhaps `Phone1` matches `ANI` and `Phone2` matches `DNIS`), in which case it's up to you how to resolve or combine them (perhaps using `groupby()`).

Comment: Thanks John, this works but is also a bit too slow to process a million rows of data.

Comment: @RileyHun: Define "a bit too slow."  How long does this solution take, and what is your goal for running time?

Comment: Some of the phone numbers are duplicates, so I created a new column that derived the unique set, thus limiting the number of phone number columns from 3 to 2. Once I did this, your code worked relatively fast. Thanks for your help